# EF defer setting property until insert

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

```
public class User {
    int Id { set; get; } // autogenerated on insert
    public string Username { set; get; }
}
```

Then some where in my code I have the follow:

```
var user = new User();
user.Username = string.Format("user{0}", user.Id);
dbContext.User.Add(user);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
Debug.WriteLine(user.Username); // outputs "User0" when the Id is ..not 0
```

Comment: Id and Username properties are not related. So if you set the UserName property it will not be changed if the Id changes since nothing is changing the UserName property.

Answer (score 1):

You're inserting a newly created user instead of inserting the one you created:

Change :

```
var user = new User();
user.Username = string.Format("user{0}", user.Id);
dbContext.User.Add(new User());
```

to:

```
var user = new User();
user.Username = string.Format("user{0}", user.Id);
dbContext.User.Add(user);
```

Comment: Sorry, I updated my sample code that was my fault while typing up the example.

Answer (score 0):

The only way this is going to work for you is if you have your User first with an empty `Username` property, `.SaveChanges()`, and then `user.Username = string.Format(...)`, then save again.  Even if you were to write this through straight SQL, you don't know the ID of the row until the db commits the change.

What you're asking for isn't possible **EDIT** without multiple saves.